# Add title/meta keywords via textbox

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am creating a CMS in ASP. A user can add new articles.

While adding articles, the user must fill in title and some meta keywords (both in textboxes).

I really don't know how can I do this functionality:

When an user opens an article, the website must fill in the title(which is retrieved from the database) between de  tags in the source code.

Anyone who can help me? How can I add database items (which I retrieve) into the  and  tags which are located in the source code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asp.net 4.0

You can Page.MetaDescription and Meta.Keywords

http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2009/07/pagemetadescription-and.html

and If you are using lower version of asp.net then do some thing like below link from my blog.

http://www.dotnetjalps.com/2010/03/dynamically-creating-meta-tag-from.html